# Azure Databricks API to create job, job doesn't get created after successful call to the API

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows, databricks-rest-api

I am using python 3.6 to make API calls to Azure Databricks to create a job to run a specific notebook. I have followed the instruction of using the API at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs#--run-now). The only difference is I am using python rather than curl. The code I have written is as follows:

```
import requests
import os
import json


dbrks_create_job_url =  "https://"+os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']+".azuredatabricks.net//2.0/jobs/create"

DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'],
    'X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id': '/subscriptions/'+ os.environ['DBRKS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'] +'/resourceGroups/'+ os.environ['DBRKS_RESOURCE_GROUP'] +'/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/' + os.environ['DBRKS_WORKSPACE_NAME'],
    'X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token': os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN']}


body_json = """
    {
    "name": "A sample job to trigger from DevOps",
    "tasks": [
        {
        "task_key": "ExecuteNotebook",
        "description": "Execute uploaded notebook including tests",
        "depends_on": [],
        "existing_cluster_id": """ + os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"] + """,
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": "/Users/myuser/sample-notebook",
          "base_parameters": {}
        },
        "timeout_seconds": 300,
        "max_retries": 1,
        "min_retry_interval_millis": 5000,
        "retry_on_timeout": false
      }
],
    "email_notifications": {},
    "name": "my_test_job",
    "max_concurrent_runs": 1}
"""

print("Request body in json format:")
print(body_json)

response = requests.post(dbrks_create_job_url, headers=DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS, data=body_json) 

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Job created successfully!")
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
else:
    print("job failed!")
    raise Exception(response.content)
```

All the OS environment variables are sent from my Azure DevOps pipeline. However, you don't need to execute the script from a pipeline. You can execute it from your local machine as long as you have a service principal with access to a databricks workspace. To run the python script, you can replace those environment variables with your own credentials.

**Explaining the variables in the script:**

- os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']: Name of the databricks instance
- os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN']: the bearer token. You need this to authenticate your service principal or your user to databricks. Later I have explained how you can get it.
- os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN']: If the service principle you are using is not added as databricks workspace users or admins, you need this token. Later I have explained how you can get it.
- os.environ['DBRKS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID']: The Azure subscription Id where databricks workspace is.
- os.environ['DBRKS_RESOURCE_GROUP']: Name of the Azure resource group of the databricks workspace.
- os.environ['DBRKS_WORKSPACE_NAME']: Name of the Azure databricks workspace.
- os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"]: The cluster Id which will execute the job in databricks.

When I run my script, I get the status code 200 which mean it should have worked properly as shown below:

[image: Python script runs successfully]

However, when I look into list of jobs, no new job is created despite the 200 status code received! You can see below the job I have created is not there.

[image: Job is not created despite the 200 status code response.]

I also changed the API endpoint from azuredatabricks.net//2.0/jobs/create to azuredatabricks.net//2.1/jobs/create, still I get successful run but no job is being created! I can't understand what I am doing wrong. And if I am doing something wrong, how come it doesn't raise exception and gives me 200 status code.

One final point to be able to regenerate the problem I am facing: To get the above two variables for DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN and DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN, you can run the following script and manually replace os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'] and os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN'] with the printed values after script execution:

```
import requests
import json
import os


TOKEN_BASE_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + os.environ['SVCDirectoryID'] + '/oauth2/token'
TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
TOKEN_REQ_BODY = {
       'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
       'client_id': os.environ['SVCApplicationID'],
       'client_secret': os.environ['SVCSecretKey']}



def dbrks_management_token():
        TOKEN_REQ_BODY['resource'] = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
        response = requests.get(TOKEN_BASE_URL, headers=TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS, data=TOKEN_REQ_BODY)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.status_code)
        else:
            raise Exception(response.text)
        return response.json()['access_token']


def dbrks_bearer_token():
        TOKEN_REQ_BODY['resource'] = '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d'
        response = requests.get(TOKEN_BASE_URL, headers=TOKEN_REQ_HEADERS, data=TOKEN_REQ_BODY)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.status_code)
        else:
            raise Exception(response.text)
        return response.json()['access_token']

DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN = dbrks_bearer_token()
DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = dbrks_management_token()

os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'] = DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN 
os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN'] = DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN 

print("DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN",os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'])
print("DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN",os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN'])
```

- SVCDirectoryID is Azure Active Directory (AAD) service principal tenant Id
- SVCApplicationID is the value of AAD service principal client Id.
- SVCSecretKey is AAD service principal secret key.

Thank you for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up the API versions - the `tasks` array could be used only with [Jobs API 2.1](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html), but you're using Jobs API 2.0. Another error is that you have `//` between host name & path.

Just change `dbrks_create_job_url` to `"https://"+os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']+".azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/jobs/create"`

Comment: I changed the dbrks_create_job_url but again I got 200 status code with no job being created. This is what I get in prints: Job created successfully!
200
b'<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/><title>Databricks - Sign In</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=960"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><script defer="defer" src="/login/login.8764f4e9.js"></script></head><body class="light-mode">...

Comment: Ah, it’s missing api word in the url. Updated answer

Comment: Alright, at the end it worked. I made two changes:
1. dbrks_create_job_url = "https://"+os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']+".azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/jobs/create"

Before 2.1 we need to put "api". Surprisingly it also worked with 2.0.
2. The request body  os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"] needed to be sorrounded by "".  For that I defined: CLUSTER_ID = "\"" + os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"] + "\"" and then added this value to the body_json value. I put it in next comment.

Comment: CLUSTER_ID = "\"" + os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"] + "\""

body_json = """
    {
    "name": "A sample job to trigger from DevOps",
    "tasks": [
        {
        "task_key": "ExecuteNotebook",
        "description": "Execute uploaded notebook including tests",
        "depends_on": [],
        "existing_cluster_id": """ + CLUSTER_ID + """,
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": "/Users/erfan.ebrahimibazaz.external@trumpf.com/sample-notebook",
          "base_parameters": {}
        },
        "timeout_seconds": 300,
 ....