# Python DatabricksCLI: get_run always fails

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli

I am using the `Job_Service` API of databricks

```
job={"run_name":"Pythonjob","existing_cluster_id": "xxx","notebook_task":{"notebook_path": "xxx"}}
jobs_service=service.JobsService(api_client)
running_job=jobs_service.submit_run(json.dumps(job))
```

Independent of the content of `job` I get the error message:

```
HTTP 400 Client Error: Bad Request for URL xxx
Respone from server: {'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE',
'message': 'One of job_clsuter_key, new_cluster or existing_cluster_id must be sepecified.'
```

In the logs I found that the REST Endpoint `api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit` is used. The example provided [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs.html) does not work either. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you please mention the error message? seems like you have pasted the code again instead of the error message.

Comment: sry, wrong code snippet

Comment: May I ask - what exactly you are trying ? Are you trying to get the logs of the run ? or trying to run a notebook ?

Comment: Try based on example questions [Ex - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153505/calling-databricks-notebook-using-databricks-job-api-runs-submit-endpoint) and [Ex - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388513/azure-databricks-api-to-create-job-job-doesnt-get-created-after-successful-cal) you could try hard coding once to check...

Comment: @rainingdistros: I want to wait until the job is completed - so I am interested in the status information

Comment: Just an idea - provided you know the job name - why not get the job id and loop till it is not running any more ? `databricks jobs list --all | grep <Job_Name> | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1
**<Job Id>**
databricks runs list --job-id <Job Id> | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3
**RUNNING**`